# What's up with my hat?

Tags: bug, status-completed

## HELP, I CAN'T SEE!

[image: its dark in here]

The fancy RPG border around our gravatars is great, but its making it hard to wear a hat.

I love hats, please let me wear it on the center of my head!

Comment: This is a total nitpick but hopefully I'm not the only one who cares so deeply about my hat =)

Comment: Do you have your browser zoomed in at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the RPG.se user page has special CSS around the big gravatar (fancy border). We're going to push a javascript fix to move the hat to the correct location in the next build.